# Unclear parse errors when translating complex PSQL query to SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have been doing some analysis on the [Lumen](https://lumendatabase.org/) database and have recently swapped to spark as the csv's are >100GB and too hefty for a single machine.

Most of my queries are running fine, however, the following seems to be having some issues:

```
psql = "select b.*, "\
"(select count(distinct c.notice_sender) from lumen_sender_duplicate_utility c where c.domain_name = b.domain_name and cast(c.num_of_dup_urls as int) = 0 ) num_of_distinct_senders "\
"from (select a.domain_name, sum(a.num_of_url) total_num_urls, "\
"sum(a.num_of_dup_urls) total_num_dup_urls, count(distinct a.notice_sender) total_num_senders " \
"from lumen_sender_duplicate a group by a.domain_name) b"
```

There have been a variety of errors as I have changed it around, but the most recent is the following: (full stack trace available at https://pastebin.com/raw/Xk4wVDmD)

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find count(DISTINCT notice_sender)#419L in [domain_name#13,sum(cast(num_of_url#14 as double))#415,sum(cast(num_of_dup_urls#16 as double))#416,count(notice_sender#10)#417L]
     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

Initially I though this was because some features such as distinct or subqueries were not available, but I am using spark 2.4 and everything seems fine to that end. (I have also tested each of the components separately and there doesn't seem to be an issue). If anyone has an idea of where I am going wrong, any help would be much appreciated.